# My server turns off after I exit

Tags: 14.04, server, power-management, shutdown

I have my **server** set so that it is always on with **AC power**. I can **login** to my server, but when I `exit` **my user** from the server it **shuts off**. I usually have it on my login page before I **close the lid**, does this have to do with anything?

It seems **like it shut off** or having no users active changed something, and I **can not connect?**

Why is this and how can I avoid this?

Comment: Closing the lid triggers suspension.

Comment: yeah, I changed that.